# How can I share a built .NET Core project between many jobs in Azure pipelines?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-core-3.0

```
- job: buildAndTestJob
 steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      vstsFeed:  $(vstsFeed)
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build'
    inputs:
      arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet test'
    inputs:
      command: test
      arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: copy bin files
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      contents: '**/bin/**/*'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: copy obj files
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      contents: '**/obj/**/*'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: publish build artifacts
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: buildeffect
      publishLocation: 'Container'


-job: packAndPushJob
  steps:
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    displayName: download build artifacts
    inputs:
      buildType: 'current'
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'buildeffect'
      downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: copy files to source directory
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/buildeffect'
      contents: '**/*'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      allowPackageConflicts: true
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet pack'
    inputs:
      arguments: '--no-restore'
      nobuild: true
      command: pack
      projects: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      publishWebProjects: true
      publishVstsFeed: $(vstsFeed)
      includeNuGetOrg: true
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'nuGet push'
    inputs:
      command: push
      projects: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      publishVstsFeed: $(vstsFeed)
      allowPackageConflicts: true
```

I have 2 jobs. First, to restore, test, build and share build files in a build artifact. Second to pack and push nuget packages. First job finished their job with success, but second job failed during pack task. It have a problem with nuget packages, for example:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.CSharp, version 4.6.0 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Spotio.Leads.Client/Spotio.Leads.Client.csproj]
```

So, maybe should we share builded project in another way? Or maybe add some parameters with feeds to restore? I don't have any idea, so please, if you have any suggestions, help us :)

Comment: have you tried azure pipeline's "nuget command" before publishing?  and make sure to clear the restore nuGet packages checkbox

Comment: Do you mean to place nuget pack before publish artifacts in first job? Yes it works, but we need to do it separate jobs

Comment: @SebastianSarnecki Try to add `--no-build` in the pack arguments.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk after added --no-build still the same result

Comment: When using `dotnet pack` command, dotnet cli will try to confirm the referenced packages exists though the project had been built and the assemblies had been output. I assume you're using a hosted agent, for this, you need to restore the packages before using the dotnet pack command in second agent job...

Comment: @SebastianSarnecki Hi friend, do you succeed to resolve that issue? Please check if you can get some help from  my suggestion. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I share a built .NET Core project between many jobs in Azure
>   pipelines?

1.See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) : Projects using the `PackageReference` format always use packages directly from this folder(`%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`).

2.Project that targets `.net core` uses `PackageReference` format, so the restored packages are stored in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` in **first agent**.

3.For your **second agent job**, devops actually start **another** hosted agent to run your tasks. It means for **second agent**, it doesn't have the referenced packages in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`.

4.Something we should know is that: Though we've copied all files of `bin` and `obj` to **second agent**, `dotnet pack xx.csproj` will still try to confirm the referenced packages exist, then the issue occurs.

So I suggest you can add a `dotnet restore` task before that `dotnet pack` task in **second agent job** to make sure the missing packages can be found in **second agent**.

**Note:**

1.In one build pipeline with two agent jobs, though these two agent jobs all use hosted agent, these two agent is not the same instance.

2.Make sure the configuration you use to build is the same configuration you use to pack.

Hope it helps. If i misunderstand anything, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, We have had a similar resolution in the previous versions, but we thought that it can work faster without restoring step. Anyway, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help :)